# COD Black Ops Multiplayer - Is there a way to practice with killstreak rewards?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

There have been countless fails I have committed when I got to use a new killstreak reward.

For example, this one time I got a valkyrie rocket and like a moron I thought that the goggles on the screen just let you command some kind of UAV that shoots rockets at places you mark on the map. Turns out that the goggles were the 'scope' for the valkyrie rocket launcher.... This ended up hilariously with me going prone inside a safe room and launching the rocket, only to have it explode on the floor 2 feet from my face :)

Even more annoying is the time I worked SO hard to get a gunship and was immediately shot down as I only knew how to control it and shoot the gun (using RT on the Xbox). I had no idea about using chaff or rockets.

Is there a way for me to try out and play around with killstreak rewards?

Comment: lol @ valkyrie incident

Comment: lol yeah. I should have captured that....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set those killstreaks to one kill in a custom match and kill a bot and then practice with it. That's what I would do.

Comment: Hmmm let me go try this out. I didn't know you could do that....

Comment: I haven't ranked up enough to set custom killstreaks but for now at recruit difficulty, I'm able to rack up killstreaks fairly fast so this answer was helpful enough to point me in the right direction :)